# detailTextLabel textalignment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I am trying to get the cell detail text to be centered.

I have read all kinds of posts on this but they all seem to be talking about older versions of IOS. I think I tried every combination of posts but no luck in making it work.

```
[[cell detailTextLabel] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

I tried this from willDisplayCell and also in the code below, neither works. Note 2 ways of doing this I tried in both methods.

Does anyone know if this does work or should I create my own center function (method)?

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
    }


    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0];


    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont  systemFontOfSize:16];


    NSMutableDictionary *curRow = [myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [curRow objectForKey:@"Description"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [curRow objectForKey:@"Stats"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Alignment is problem for you then you can create custom labels and add subview to the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    UILabel *label;
    UILabel *detailLabel;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 4, 260, 20)] autorelease];
        //make Your alignments to this label
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
        label.tag=25;

        //make Your alignments to this detail label
        detailLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 25, 260, 15)] autorelease];
        detailLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
        detailLabel.tag=30;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
    }
    else
    {
        label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:25];
        detailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:30];
    }
    label.text =[curRow objectForKey:@"Description"];
    detailLabel.text=[curRow objectForKey:@"Stats"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can I also make a 3rd subview or does the style stop that?

Comment: When you are customizing the cell you dont need to worry about the style. You can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if you want to center the `detailTextLabel` while still making use of the automatic vertical center (textLabel will be vertically centered, if the `detailTextLabel` is empty) you need to override `- (void) layoutSubviews`.

Otherwise the label's size will fit the content, and therefore `textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter` will not work.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```