# UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle text alignment

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I made lot's of googling but found no solution :(

Is there any way to change the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` text alignment?

Comment: how do you set the value for subtitle...?

Comment: this might have your answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591409/detailtextlabel-textalignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you cannot change it, 
I also had this same problem, and after a lot of googling i found that writing my own custom cell (that took me 10 minutes) was much more productive that doing further research 
So my advice is, drop the search and start coding your own cell with subtitle

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only way for align-subtitle is to make your own custom cell class.